# Entity Framework - conditional relation - One Child table to one or other parrent table

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am trying to create a project of data base using code first and Data annotations, but I have some doubts about architecture. I am not sure if my schema of relations make sense, is correct in SQL and possible to implement in EF. How to make a conditional relations from one child table to one of two parrent tables.
In my ProcessRelation Table I would save both relations. JobBusinessArea - Estimates and jobBussinesArea - PriceList. I hope it makes sence. Thanks for any help and suggestions.

```
[Table("ProcessRelation")]
    public class ProcessRelation
    {
        [Key, Column("AreaId", Order = 0)]
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column("ModId", Order = 1)]
        public int ModId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column("PriceSourceTypeId", Order = 2)]
        public int PriceSourceTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CrtUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime CrtTmstmp { get; set; }
        public int LcUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime LcTmstmp { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PriceSourceTypeId")]
        public virtual BillingProjectCode PriceSourceTypeCode { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AreaId")]
        public virtual JobBusinessArea JobBusinessArea { get; set; }

        //TODO:
        //Depending on the PriceSourceTypeId i would like create reference to PriceListProcessMod Table 
    //or EstimateProcessMod Table
        //[ForeignKey("ModId")]
        //public virtual PriceListProcessMod PriceListProcessMod { get; set; }
        // or
        //public virtual EstimateProcessMod EstimateProcessMod { get; set; }
    }


[Table("PriceListProcessMod")]
    public class PriceListProcessMod
    {
        [Key, Column("ModId", Order = 0)]
        public int ModId { get; set; }
        public int ProcessId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
        public int CrtUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime CrtTmstmp { get; set; }
        public int LcUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime LcTmstmp { get; set; }
        public decimal? CommisionPercentage { get; set; }
        public bool? IsProportionalyFixed { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProcessId")]
        public virtual PriceListProcess PriceListProcess { get; set; }
    }

[Table("EstimateProcessMod")]
    public class EstimateProcessMod
    {
        [Key, Column("ModId", Order = 0)]
        public int ModId { get; set; }
        public int? SplitId { get; set; }
        public int ProcessId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
        public int CrtUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime CrtTmstmp { get; set; }
        public int LcUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime LcTmstmp { get; set; }
        public decimal? CommisionPercentage { get; set; }
        public bool? IsProportionalyFixed { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProcessId")]
        public virtual EstimateProcess EstimateProcess{ get; set; }
    }

 [Table("JobBusinessArea")]
    public class JobBusinessArea
    {
        [Key, Column("JobBusinessAreaId", Order = 0)]
        public int JobBusinessAreaId { get; set; }

        public int CrtUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime CrtTmstmp { get; set; }
        public int LcUsrnm { get; set; }
        public DateTime LcTmstmp { get; set; }

        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int AreaTypeId { get; set; }
        public int SourceId { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: There is no conditional Relationship in SQL or, for that matter, EF. A FK column will target exactly one target PK column. For your case, you should use nullable navigation properties/FK's, possibly paired with TPH inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems EstimateProcessMod and PriceListProcessMod have lot in common. I would suggest to take advantage of it and store both entities in a single table ProcessMod. By creating ProcessMod abstract class and annotating it with `Table attribute`. Concrete classes will define only the differences.

```
[Table("ProcessMod")]
public abstract class ProcessMod
{
    [Key, Column("ModId", Order = 0)]
    public int ModId { get; set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
    public int CrtUsrnm { get; set; }
    public DateTime CrtTmstmp { get; set; }
    public int LcUsrnm { get; set; }
    public DateTime LcTmstmp { get; set; }
    public decimal? CommisionPercentage { get; set; }
    public bool? IsProportionalyFixed { get; set; }
}

public class EstimateProcessMod : ProcessMod
{
    public int? SplitId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProcessId")]
    public virtual EstimateProcess EstimateProcess{ get; set; }
}

public class PriceListProcessMod : ProcessMod
{
    [ForeignKey("ProcessId")]
    public virtual PriceListProcess PriceListProcess { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProcessRelation")]
public class ProcessRelation
{
    [Key, Column("AreaId", Order = 0)]
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column("ModId", Order = 1)]
    public int ModId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column("PriceSourceTypeId", Order = 2)]
    public int PriceSourceTypeId { get; set; }
    public int CrtUsrnm { get; set; }
    public DateTime CrtTmstmp { get; set; }
    public int LcUsrnm { get; set; }
    public DateTime LcTmstmp { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriceSourceTypeId")]
    public virtual BillingProjectCode PriceSourceTypeCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AreaId")]
    public virtual JobBusinessArea JobBusinessArea { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModId")]
    public virtual ProcessMod ProcessMod { get; set; }
}
```

You probably can get rid of PriceSourceTypeId in the ProcessRelation class and move it to ProcessMod class and make it discriminator or maybe you don't need to use it at all. It really depends on the rest of the application.

You might be interested in [Table per Hierarchy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) to understand how it works.